# Android SQLite selection args upper/down case issue for non Latin strings

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Listview which is based on CursorAdapter. I have implemented filtering functionality to it and everything works fine, except one thing:
When I type in the SearchView in Latin letters it filters as expected - without putting difference between upper/down case letters. So when I have "John Smith" in my list I can filter it with "john", but for none Latin letters this doesn't work. When I have a name starting with upper case and I type in SearchView with lower case it doesn't find the name.

Here is the part of code that can be interesting:

```
String loaclSelection = SELECTION + " AND " + CONTACT_NAME + " LIKE ?";
String localArgs = new String[]{"%"+constraintString+"%"};

return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), 
    URI, 
    PROJETION, 
    loaclSelection, 
    localArgs,
    SORT_ORDER);
```

constraintString is the string from searchView.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There's `COLLATE UNICODE` in Android sqlite but it doesn't really work with `LIKE`.

Consider the following:

1. Add another column where you store the name in lower case, converted in Java using `String.toLowerCase()`.
2. Use similar lowercasing for your search terms in Java.
3. Use the original mixed case field for display purposes.

Comment: The problem is, that I search in ContactsProvider, the names are the contact names and I don't really want to make a copy of them in a local database. I just wonder why it works with Latin strings but not work for example with indian, russina etc.